# Not able to record the testcase using jmeter getting this error:-[52293] Not implemented (probably used https)

Tags: jmeter

I am recording a web-based application using jmeter but getting this error:

```
ERROR o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [52293]  Not implemented (probably used https)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only ASCII supported in headers (perhaps SSL was used?)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.HttpRequestHdr.parse(HttpRequestHdr.java:138) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.3]
```

- Using chrome browser
- Using JMeter Version 5.3
- Have downloaded ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt certificate also
- Have checked env variable also , that is also fine
- Using java version 1.8.0_281

We are getting request only when we are entering credential, but after that not getting any request in jmeter recording controller.(It is also not able to login into the application using proxy)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you told JMeter you will be recording [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) traffic and you're trying to record [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) instead, change `schemeToRecord` to `https` and the issues should go away:

[image]

Also [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) (or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)

And last but not the least, if you're using Chrome you might want to try out [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies, protocols and certificates.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have tried this approach but this is not worked for me, error is still same, not able to record, after entering username/password, page is not loading (using proxy tool jmeter)